# No WiFi in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, realtek-wireless

In my Ubuntu 18.04 I can't WiFi adapter. When I run `iwconfig` this happens:

```
arka@arka-HP-ProBook-450-G3:~$ iwconfig
enp1s0    no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

and I am not able to install any network driver. How can i resolve this situation?

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`:

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf line 8: ignoring bad line starting with '“options'
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:804c]
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:522a] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [103c:8101]
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86151/discussion-on-question-by-arka-bhuiyan-no-wifi-in-ubuntu-18-04).

Comment: any one can help me out??
i am still stuck at it

Comment: Please provide the contents of lines 7-8-9 of the file ` /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` and leave a comment @Fabby